# How to search for a particular user in a list of millions of user objects?

Tags: java

Lets say I have a User class like below,

```
class User {
  int id;
  String emailAddress; 
}
```

and lets say I have a list of millions of such users. It could be anything array or array list or anything.

Now, given a User with id or emailAddress, how do I efficiently search for a particular user e.g. search by id or search by emailAddress independently.

Comment: Use a Database.

Comment: @ScaryWombat. Unfortunately this data is coming from some other source and I have to do this in memory only.

Comment: If you really have to keep it in memory have a look at hash tables.

Comment: @Henry, yes but then it will search by either id or emailAddress , if I use one of them as a key.

Comment: Nothing hinders you to use two tables.

Comment: Not sure how and why you have millions of objects in memory like that. As suggested in the previous comment, use a database (probably in-memory if you want to make it much faster). Or do your own indexing. For example, you can have the objects sorted so that you can use binary search for finding by id.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 possible ways to solve your problem and both solution depends on your current architecture.

1. If you are getting the User data from the database then just make two search method. the first search method contains a where clause of the user ID and the other search method contains a where clause of the user email.
2. If you are not getting the User data from the database then you can make user of various search algorithms that are already implemented. A picture below contains the time complexity of some search and sort algorithms. But for me it is better to sort the data first using merge sort then use binary search.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use two map,one map id to user,another map emailAddress to User,simple code like this:

```
public class UserCache {
    Map<Integer, List<User>> id2User = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    Map<String, List<User>> email2User = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void initMaps(List<User> users) {
        id2User.putAll(users.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getId)));
        email2User.putAll(users.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getEmailAddress)));
    }

    public List<User> getUsersById(String id) {
        return id2User.get(id);
    }

    public List<User> getUserByEmail(String email) {
        return email2User.get(email);
    }

    public void deleteUserById(String id) {
        List<User> users = id2User.remove(id);
        users.stream()
            .forEach(user -> email2User.remove(user.getEmailAddress()));
    }

    public void deleteUserByEmail(String email) {
        List<User> users = email2User.remove(email);
        users.stream()
            .forEach(user -> id2User.remove(user.getId()));
    }
}
```